# Nginx proxy_pass not working without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, mod-proxy, proxypass

I've done some searching on this issue and have found other posts similar to this one, but none of the solutions have helped me.

I've got a `location` entry in my Nginx config which contains a `proxy_pass` rule, but it only seems to work when I add a trailing slash to the URL.

Here's the location stanza

```
    location  /webApp {
        proxy_pass         https://webapp.service.consul/webApp;
        proxy_set_header   Host webapp.service.consul;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

You can see, when I use `curl` and go out to `/webApp/` (with trailing slash), it works fine - and the cookie is set as expected:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ $ curl -I https://example.com/webApp/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 14:45:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=440B8D729469BBD80FC92796754D9475; Path=/providerApp/; HttpOnly
Location: http://webapp.service.consul/webApp/login.do;jsessionid=440B8D729469BBD80FC92796754D9475
```

However, when I go out to `/webApp` (no trailing slash), I get a `302 Found`, but I don't get redirected to the `/webApp/login.do` page as I did with the trailing slash:

```
MacBook-Pro:~$ curl -I https://example.com/webApp
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 14:48:44 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://webapp.service.consul/webApp/
```

I have tried add a rewrite rule, something like:

`rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.  This was working before, and I haven't really messed with this location stanza, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with one of my other locations.

Any tips?

Comment: I guess you should fix your consul app

Comment: @Alexey, what do you mean?  The consul app works fine when adding the trailing slash (or when bypassing Nginx completely).

Comment: This redirect issued by consul, not nginx. BTW, show full nginx's config and I can't understand is it really redirect's you to `webapp.service.consul`?

Comment: I think what I really want to do is redirect `/webApp` to `/webApp/login.do` on the first visit, and then send to proxy_pass.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually specify ***IN WHICH WAY*** is it not working, but it sounds like an issue that should be fixable by [the `proxy_redirect` directive](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect).

```
proxy_redirect http://webapp.service.consul/webApp/ http://example.com/webApp/
```

(However, the best solution might be to just ensure that the hostnames are correctly specified in the rest of the configuration files.)